# Video from database

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, video, html5-video

I store videos on database. 
Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetMp4(decimal subtaskId)
    {
        //var result = File(_subtaskService.GetById(subtaskId).VideoMP4, "video/mp4", "video.mp4");
        //return result;

        var result = Json(_subtaskService.GetById(subtaskId).VideoMP4, "video/mp4", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        result.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return result;
    }
```

_subtaskService.GetById(subtaskId).VideoMP4 returns byte[]

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var link;

    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetMp4", new {subtaskId = Model.Id})", function (data) {
        var blob = new Blob(data, { type: 'video/mp4' });            
        link = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        $('#srcmp4').attr('src', link);
    });
```

Html:

```
<video controls>
<source type="video/ogg"/>
<source id ="srcmp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

I get the data and url, but video doesn't work. When i download blob and rename to mp4 file it doesn't work too. What did i wrong?

And if i do this:
Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetMp4(decimal subtaskId)
    {
        var result = File(_subtaskService.GetById(subtaskId).VideoMP4, "video/mp4", "video.mp4");
        return result;            
    }
```

Html:

```
<video preload ="metadata" controls>*@
<source type="video/ogg" src="@Url.Action("GetOgg", new {subtaskId = Model.Id})"/>*@
<source type="video/mp4" src="@Url.Action("GetMp4", new {subtaskId = Model.Id})"/>*@
</video>
```

video works, but timeline is wrong.

p.s. sory for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting the data as a dataURI or JSON? It seems so, you need to convert it to an ArrayBuffer if a dataURI or make the AJAX request typed as an ArrayBuffer before the blob.